# How to read an entire excel file as an array?

Tags: r

My `"Data.xlsx"` consists of 10 sheets. Each sheet representing one city with some data having different dimensions i.e each sheet of different rows but same number of columns.

I tried this

```
City_Data <- array(NA, dim = c(160,13,10));

for (istation in 1:10) {
  City_Data[,,istation] <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx",istation)
}
```

But is there any other way to store the entire data automatically (like a function) in an array?
Note that I have taken row number as 160 because it is the maximum number of observations or rows of all the sheets.

Comment: Is this the read.xlsx function from the openxlsx package?

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity to use `openxlsx` or `readxl` with `purrr`:  https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html#iterate-over-multiple-worksheets-in-a-workbook

Comment: @Stijn It is from 'xlsx' package.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `readxl` and `lapply` to read in each sheet into a list. This will generate a list where each element is one of the sheets (stored as a dataframe object in R). Try this:

```
library(readxl)

sheetVector <- c('sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3')

sheetList <- lapply(
  sheetVector,
  function(sheet){
    read_xlsx(path = 'Data.xlsx', sheet = sheet)
  }
)
```

This will return a list containing the three sheets named in `sheetVector`. If you want to combine the sheets into a single data frame: `sheetDF <- rbindlist(sheetList)`.